# Safari 5.1.4 printing two pages for blank html file

Tags: macos, safari

I am using Mac OSX 10.6.8 and Safari 5.1.4. 
When I am trying to print a blank html page I am getting two blank pages instead of one. This is happening for all small(hello world) html pages. I just took the extreme example of blank html by writing 'about:blank' in the safari address bar.
The printer I am using is a network printer 'HP Color laser jet 2025'. 
When I prints to a PDF I again gets two pages.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Even an empty html document results in 2 pages being printed. I have come to the conclusion that Safari is poo and any time spent trying to support it is wasted time. PS it crashes 10 seconds after I load it up every time just to add to the annoyance factor :) nice one Apple